# SQL Server xml copy values of one node to another

Tags: sql-server, xml

I want to copy the values of one node to another in sql server(2005 and 2008).
e.g if one of the xml data is as below

```
 <Data>
<Name></Name>
<ShortName>Joe</ShortName>
</Data>
```

the resulting xml should be

```
<Data>
<Name>Joe</Name>
<ShortName>Joe</ShortName>
```

the update statement should affect all the rows in the table

appreciate any help 
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to watch out for [Silent XQuery failures](http://blogs.msdn.com/denisruc/archive/2007/04/19/silent-xquery-failures.aspx).

The problem in this case is that XPath expression (/Data/Name/text())[1](http://blogs.msdn.com/denisruc/archive/2007/04/19/silent-xquery-failures.aspx) returns an empty sequence. ‘Name’ is an empty element (It has no children). Therefore the expression (/Data/Name/text())[1](http://blogs.msdn.com/denisruc/archive/2007/04/19/silent-xquery-failures.aspx) doesn’t point to any existing node. The solution to this problem is to insert a new text node inside the Name element, like this:

```
DECLARE @myDoc xml
SET @myDoc = '<Data>
    <Name></Name>
    <Name2>dd</Name2>
    <ShortName>Joe</ShortName>
</Data>'

SELECT @myDoc

if (@myDoc.exist('(/Data/Name/text())[1]') = 1) BEGIN
    set @myDoc.modify('
        replace value of (/Data/Name/text())[1]
        with (/Data/ShortName/text())[1]
    ')
end else begin
    set @myDoc.modify('
        insert (/Data/ShortName/text())[1]
        as first into (/Data/Name)[1]
    ')
end

SELECT @myDoc
```

Comment: great tip. i did encounter this issue but forgot to mention it in the post.

Comment: I'm glad you caught it.  Don't forget to accept this answer if you found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

got the solution
update table set col.modify(replace value of (/Name/text())[1] with  (/ShortName/text())[1])

Comment: There is an error in your solution.  See my answer for more information.